# Why do I have duplicates headers on Apache 2.4?

Tags: apache, http-headers

When I send a header `X-foo: bar` to Apache from my backend and I configure Apache with:

```
Header setifempty X-foo "baz"
```

I receive two `X-foo headers` instead of one with "baz" value.

I use the version 2.4.41 httpd (docker image).

Is it a bug or a misconfig?

Comment: Perhaps the backend adds the header afterwards :-?

Comment: The backend sends only one `X-foo`. :/

Comment: I’ve noticed this a few time’s in Chrome on various sites and think it’s a display bug. Try from another browser and/or curl and make sure it’s a real issue.

Comment: Yes, but perhaps it adds the header after mod_header does so `setifempty` does not have the chance to work as expected. It's just an hypothesis, I'm not familiar with that module and I don't know how your backend works.

Comment: I used curl to be sure before posting. And the backend is a PHP-FPM and the header is set by the classical `header()` function.